# How to box a dynamic type

Tags: rust

I've implemented a series of methods that return a dynamic type, `impl Iterator`. How do you create a method that boxes this?

MRE:

```rust
enum Value {
    Number(f64)
}

pub trait IterValue {
    fn iter_value(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Value>;
}

impl IterValue for ndarray::Array1<f64> {
    fn iter_value(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Value> {
        self.slice(ndarray::s![0..10]).into_iter().map(move |&n| Value::Number(n))
    }
}

fn test(x: ndarray::Array1<Value>, y: ndarray::Array2<Value>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Value>> {
    Box::new(x.iter_value().into_iter())
}
```

As you can see, the last line will fail because it is capturing a value that exists only temporarily. However, this was perfectly OK for the iter_value function.

Comment: Are you okay with keeping `x` alive too? Do you need to support `Iterator` implementations that borrow, or would `impl Iterator<Item = Value> + 'static` be acceptable? (Also, have you considered taking `x` and `y` as references themselves?) There’s a lot to pick between here, and no generic answer, so feel free to ask about the underlying issue that prompted the box instead of potentially suffering from [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes. I would love to keep `x` alive as long as the iterator is around. The iterator will almost certainly be gone soon but `x` will be around for a while.

Comment: The `XY Problem` is that I want to iterate over an enum with many heterogenous variants, each of which have a different concrete iterator type.

Comment: I'll ask the question directly in those terms: this is perhaps a bit too narrow.

Comment: If you know that the iteratee will outlive the iterator, why does the iterator need to be boxed?

Comment: I guess (though it should really be included in MRE) that there are several such `impl Iterator`s, which have to be processed in the same way, hence the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: [Here's how you can do it if `x` will be kept alive](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=08c0b21e6213b9d46adf6fbaaedab338).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this returns only "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
"

Comment: This is an error in the playground, it happens from time to time. Wait some time and try again, or run it locally.